# Scheduled long running c# jobs in aws

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, service

I have a legacy .net standard windows service that uses an IScheduler to execute various long running jobs at certain times of day.  I will migrate the code to .net core.  I want to get rid of the windows service and run these either serverless or somehow in an aws linux ec2, like with docker or something.  I was considering lambda but it has a hard 5 minute timeout, and I'd like to avoid re-architecting the .net code so that it runs in less time or in batches.  What are some of my options within aws to migrate my c# windows service to a non-windows c# solution?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested at the [AWS  Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=244383) by Jamie@AWS.

The best way to run a scheduled batch job is by using AWS Cloud Watch Event + AWS Lambda + AWS Batch.

You schedule a AWS Cloud Watch Event that triggers Lambda.
Then Lambda submits a batch job to AWS Batch and a Docker container handles the execution.

Comment: Lambda has a hard 5 minute timeout, I don't want to re-architect this code to run in under 5 minutes.

Comment: Lambda only submits the batch job, this proccess takes less than a second. Then lamda dies and AWS Batch handle everything.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing the Linux route possibly, why don't you consider running a cron job?  You can schedule your programs to run at certain times of day.

Windows of course has similar functions also.

Comment: What kind of c# 'program' would i write that could be executed with cron?  Can a c# console app somehow be triggered with cron?

Comment: .NET core has console application support - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio.  You'll of course need to verify your code is .NET core compatible,  it could potentially involve changes not just to how you are running it.

Comment: Will I need a dedicated ec2 for this?  Can I schedule long running c# code to run with aws without a dedicated server?

Comment: You'll need your own instance for that, yes.